# Homework advice-- Ordered fields and the rationals

Tags: real-analysis

This is a homework problem, so do not give answers. Does anyone have any advice about how to approach this problem? I am not too sure how or where to start. Here is the problem:

Show that the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ form an ordered field which satisfies the Archimedean property.  What property of real numbers $\mathbb{R}$ is not satisfied by $\mathbb{Q}$?

The definition for an ordered field: An ordered field is a field $\mathbb{F}$ which is also an ordered set, such that

$(i)\hspace{10mm}  x+y < x + z  $  if $x,y,z \in \mathbb{F}$ and $y<z$

$ (ii) \hspace{10mm}xy >0$ if $x,y \in \mathbb{F}, x > 0, y > 0$

For the first part do I start by assuming $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field and an ordered set, then show that it satisfies the two axioms in the definition for an ordered field? Or am I supposed to show the set $\mathbb{Q}$ is ordered field by showing it satisfies the axioms for an ordered set, then show it satisfies the axioms of a field, then show it also satisfies the axioms in the definition for an ordered field? What I mean by show is let $x=m/n$ where $x\in\mathbb{Q}$ and $n,m \in \mathbb{Z},$ and $n \neq 0$, and  similarly for $y = k/h$ and $z = p/q$. What are your thoughts and what is your advice or suggestion? I still don't even know how I would approach the second part about the Archimedean Property. Here was an attempt at a proof (I suppose) that was completely random. I started with assuming $\mathbb{Q}$ is an ordered field. Then I have for $$ x + y < x + z \implies (m/n) + (k/h) < (m/n)+(p/q) \implies (m/n)-(m/n) + (k/h) < (m/n)-(m/n) + (p/q) \implies(k/h) < (p/q) \implies y < x$$ and it also implies $qk < hp$. I don't know what this would mean as far as the progression of a proof, but the inequality appears to be like the Archimedean Property, but it isn't necessarily so.

Answer (score 1):

> > Show that the rational numbers $\mathbb{Q}$ form an ordered field...
>
> For the first part do I start by assuming $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field and an ordered set, then show that it satisfies the two axioms in the definition for an ordered field?

No, that isn't enough. Until you prove that $\mathbb Q$ is a field, it's *conceivable* that it isn't!

Consider a different example. The integers $\mathbb Z$ are an integral domain -- *almost* a field -- and an ordered set, and $\mathbb Z$ even obeys the axioms *(i)* and *(ii)*. So if you weren't careful to check every single field axiom, you might conclude that $\mathbb Z$ is an ordered field, which is wrong!

> Or am I supposed to show the set $\mathbb{Q}$ is ordered field by showing it satisfies the axioms for an ordered set, then show it satisfies the axioms of a field, then show it also satisfies the axioms in the definition for an ordered field?

Yes.

> > ... which satisfies the Archimedean property.

You need to show that for all $p/q\in\mathbb Q$, there exists an integer $n$ such that $n>p/q$. The $n$ that you find should depend on $p$ and/or $q$ somehow. There are many possible choices.

The inequality that you displayed doesn't have much to do with the Archimedean property, as far as I can tell.

Comment: Don't you mean that if $(p/q), (k/h) \in \mathbb{Q}$, there exists an integer $n$ such that $n (p/q)> (k/h)$, or are they equivalent.

Comment: In a field, it suffices to fix one of the elements to be $1$. That said, there are many equivalent definitions of the Archimedean property, and you can use whichever one you're the most comfortable with. I don't know what definition(s) you've seen, so I can't choose for you.

Comment: So when you are showing that $\mathbb{Q}$ is a field do I let $x=(m/n)$ (as for $y$ and $z$), and then brute force through the definition? By that I mean doing a direct proof until the simplified equality is not contradicting? For example, assume the rationals are not commutative. Then $(m/n)+(p/q) \neq (p/q) + (m/n)$. After some algebra, the result is $1\neq1$. The contradiction implies that the premise was false. Is this what should be done? Being careful only to use integer addition and multiplication.

Comment: The *direct* approach is to compute $x+y$ and $y+x$ from the definition of addition in $\mathbb Q$, and show that they're equal. You probably won't need a proof-by-contradiction for any part of the exercise (although attempting one may help order your thoughts).

Comment: Yes, that is true-- as long as I use integer division and multiplication so to avoid using commutative properties of the rationals? Thanks for the advice by the way.

Comment: Right, you don't want a circular proof, whatever your strategy is!